# I can't map correctly an Excel file to postgreSQL using Talend. the id cannot be forced from the input file

Tags: postgresql, talend

I have a simple xls file (excel), I have a column N_ENR which contains numeric values (the primary keys from a table).

I'm using Talend.

Now, I want to save all the records into a potgreSQL table (table client), the problem is that my output table (table client) generates new ids, the other columns are mapped correctly (address, date, phoneNumber, ...).

I changed the type of the primary key (id column) to serial, still didn't work.

Any suggestions ?
Thank you.

Comment: Is there an error is it just that the primary ID gets ignored and a new one is used in the database?
Also, do these IDs already exist in there? Is the table empty? You might also want to tag this with postgresql as well since it's more of a db question.

Comment: Thank you for your replay.
yes, the primary ID gets ignored and a new one is used in the database.
The problem comes from the cell format, I have for example: 2 423, even I parse correctly this String to Long, it is ignored, when I force this cell to use standand format like 2423, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to change the type of the PK column change it to 'int' and then map your source ID to that column.

Comment: Thank you for replay, I changed the Excel cell format to Integer and it works. Thank you